# Mandrill - what does auto_text do?

Tags: mandrill

as per https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html there is an auto_text parameter when sending an email via the Mandrill API. How does this work? If I leave out the text parameter will it automatically strip out HTML entities and generate a text only version of the email?

e.g. If my HTML email looks like:

Testing, testing 123

Will it just show Testing, testing 123 as the text content?

cheers,
Jeremy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, that's the idea. It will convert the HTML portion of the email to a plain-text version without HTML markup so you don't have to do it.